# How to install rpm command in offline way

Tags: rpm

Instead of installing the **rpm package**, install the **rpm binary file**.
So that make the system that missing rpm command can install the rpm package.

But the network not connect to internet, so please do not post answers like `yum install rpm` or `apt install rpm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to download rpm package (depend on distribution). Then you should exec command:

```
rpm2cpio file.rpm | cpio -idv
```

This command will convert the file to `cpio` archive and then extract/install this archive

Comment: Wow, I did not think about this!